# setting the top margin of the h1 element in the header does not work as expected

Tags: html, css

I have made use of the html5 header tag and an h1 tag within it. After setting up the top margin property of the h1 element in my header to 0px, i manage to remove the top margin of the header, but i want the h1 element inside my header to have a top margin of around 15px.

Now when i try setting the top margin of the h1 element, it also creates a top margin for the header which i don't want.

Can someone help me out with this...?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Codename : ENT</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Site Title / LOGO</h1>
        <p>Site Tagline / Slogan / One liner.</p>
        <p></p>
        <nav></nav>
    </header>
    <div id="content_wrapper"></div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and CSS

```
header {
    background-color:#ff0
}

header h1 {
    margin-top:0;
    margin-left:15px
}

header p {
    margin-left:15px
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `padding-top` for `h1` or `header` or use `overflow:hidden` for `header`

Comment: Having just scribbled an answer below, I must admit I've never seen overflow:hidden used like that before. Nice answer, but I don't understand exactly how it works...

Comment: @DarkHippo - I explained this in my answer - clearance is one way to stop margins collapsing

Answer (score 7):

The issue you are facing here is call [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Here is an excerpt from [this mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing):

> Parent and first/last child
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to
>   separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first
>   child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height,
>   min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block
>   with the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse.
>   The collapsed margin ends up **outside the parent**.

So I could fix this by adding a border to the header element - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/4Q7LE/2/)

```
header {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

or by clearence - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/4Q7LE/3/)**

```
header {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

or by adding padding -  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/4Q7LE/4/)**

```
header {
    padding: 1px;
}
```

... etc etc

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... ! appreciate it !

Comment: Awesome explaination :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned is every other answer, what you actually want is padding-top, not margin-top.

The difference between these two is pretty easy to understand, essentially padding is inside the element, and margin is outside the element, the last two examples from this tutorial show it fairly well
http://html.net/tutorials/css/lesson10.php

So with your code, the header element is the container, adding `margin-top:15px` will move the element down 15px, meaning the whole container, yellow background included, sits lower. Adding `padding-top:15px` with increase the height of the header element by 15px, by adding to the top of the element, and moving the content down, leaving a yellow gap of 15px at the top.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... ! appreciate it !

Comment: No problem. I'd much rather someone understood the answer instead of just blindly copying it into their code.

Comment: i wasn't aware of the overflow property.. but it works like a charm.. surfing the net now... for some nice explanations on it 1

Answer (score 1):

Add `padding-top: 15px;` to the properties of `h1`.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
header h1 {
    padding-top:15px;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-left:15px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/2h99X/)**

css

```
header {
    background-color:#ff0;
    margin:0;
    display: inline-block; /* add this to make it inline as <header> id block element by default */ 
    width: 100%; /* for 100% width */
}
header h1 {
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:15px
}
header p {
    margin-left:15px
}
```